# Prevent default on a click within a JQuery tabs in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery-ui, google-chrome

I would like to prevent the default behaviour of a click on a link. I tried the return false; also javascript:void(0); in the href attribute but it doesn’t seem to work. It works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome and IE.

I have a single tab that loads via AJAX the content which is a simple link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs({
                ajaxOptions: {
                    error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                        $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. If this wouldn't be a demo.");
                    },
                    success: function() {
                        alert('hello');
                        $('#lk').click(function(event) {
                            alert('Click Me');
                            event.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        });
                    }
                },
            load: function(event, ui) {
                    $('a', ui.panel).click(function(event) {
                        $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
                        event.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    });
                }           
            });
        });
</script>
<body>
      <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="linkChild.htm">Link</a></li> 
        </ul>
      </div>
</body>
```

The content of linkChild.htm is

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="lk">Click Me</a>
```

So basically when the tab content is loaded with success, a click event is attached to the link “lk”. When I click on the link, the alert is displayed but then link disappears. I check the HTML and the element is actually removed from the DOM.

Comment: Removing the load function is fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#selector').click(function(event) { 

    event.preventDefault();

});
```

The event object is passed to your click handler by default - you have to have something there to receive it. Once you have the event, you can use jQuery's `.preventDefault()` method to cancel the link's behavior.

### Edit:

Here's the fragment of your code, corrected:

```
$('a', ui.panel).click(function(event) {
   $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
   event.preventDefault(); 
   return false;
});
```

Notice the addition of the word 'event' when creating the anon function (or you could use just e, or anything else - the name is unimportant, the fact there's a var there is.

Comment: I though return false; was doing the same as event.preventDefault();. Unfortunately using .preventDefault() method is not working.

Comment: Your click handler is not catching the event. You need a varible in your click handler function like i've got in the example .. `function(event)`. and then you use `event.preventDefault()`. And return false is not cross browser. For example, in IE you need to set the `event.returnValue` property to false, which isn't the same as returning false. `.preventDefault` takes care of all the xbrowser niceities for you.

Comment: I also added the `.preventDefault` to the click handler of `lk`. I also changed the href attribute and in firebug I can see a GET request for the google site. See edited code.

Comment: I accept the answer event though it did not fix my problem. The answer actually prevents the default behavior of a click.